# How to implement autocomplete with websocket?

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

This is my very first web development project, I need to implement a search-as-you-type feature. The requirement is to use websocket. I download the file from http://www.techbysample.com/2017/03/21/getting-started-with-websockets/
 to test the connection, and I can get data back.

[Websocket testing screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntrK2.png)

Using the test file, when I type `{"type":"item","text":"bagel"}`in the input field then click the "send" button, I see data `{"results":{"results":[{"id":1822,"name":"1 oz. Cream Cheese "},{"id":1821,"name":"1 oz. Cream Cheese - 36 COUNT"},{"id":2529,"name":"1% 1 Gallon"},{"id":2528,"name":"1% 1/2 Gallon"},`

However, in my actual project, I do not have any button, I want to see the data as I type in the search field, which is inside a td in a table.

```
<td>
   <input class="item-input" type="search" name="item" value="">
</td>
```

And this is the js I wrote, I am taking one small step at a time so I just want to see if there's anything shows up in console (but eventually, the data need to show in the webpage not console):

```
let webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/autocomplete") 

webSocket.onopen = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('connected!');
  };
  webSocket.onmessage = (msgEvent) => {
    let results = JSON.parse(msgEvent.data);
    console.log(results);
  };
  webSocket.onclose = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('disconnected');
  };
  webSocket.onerror = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('there\'s an error');
  };

  /**
   *  Send Message
   */
  doSendMessage =() => {
      webSocket.send(msg.value);
      console.log(msg.value);
      msg.value = "";
  }

  let itemInput = document.querySelectorAll('.item-input');
  itemInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    doSendMessage();
  });
```

But I got the following error: `websocket_orders.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: itemInput.addEventListener is not a function(…)`

I wonder how can I implement this feature? Using vanilla js or jQuery.

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the data shows up in the console. Here is what I did:
I used jQuery, and bind the function to the `.item-input` to the table it belongs to.

```
$(function () {
  let webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/autocomplete");
  webSocket.onopen = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('connected!');
  };
  webSocket.onmessage = (msgEvent) => {
    let results = JSON.parse(msgEvent.data);
    console.log(results);
  };
  webSocket.onclose = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('disconnected');
  };
  webSocket.onerror = (msgEvent) => {
    console.log('there\'s an error');
  };

  /**
   *  Send Message
   */
   $('.add-items-table').on('input', '.item-input', (e) => {
     let value = e.target.value;
     webSocket.send(value);
     console.log(value);
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll returns a set of element nodes with the classname item-input. So it cannot attach addEventListener. Use

`let itemInput = document.querySelector('.item-input');`

querySelector returns the first element with class item-input. You can attach addEventListener to the element.

Alternative approach is use id = 'item-input' and use document.getElementById("item-input");